# I'm sorry if you think so

Tags: word-usage, phrase-usage, expressions

Can "`I'm sorry if you think so`" be used in the context where someone is looking down on me or expressing that they don't have a good opinion of me. Like, "`I think your recent work is not good`" "`I'm sorry if you think so`"

Does this sound natural to you? Or what should I say when someone is expressing disapproval of me?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Apart from the wrong choice of word, yes, that's appropriate and natural.

The thing is, you're not sorry **if** they think so. You know they think so, given they just said so, which means the conditional isn't appropriate. You are sorry **that** they think so.

It's completely natural, and can come across as rebellious, care-free, resentful, or passive aggressive, depending on tone. Probably other ways it can come across, too. Mostly it's a non-apology, a way of having the form of an apology without actually apologising. It can be otherwise, but be cautious - even if meant as a sincere expression of regret, it may be taken badly.

Comment: "I'm sorry if you think that" (with 'if' and not 'that') is perfectly normal in British English. As you note, this type of utterance is often heard as a non-apology, or something not meant, but said for the sake of form.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey: It's heard a lot, but my experience is that it's mostly used when a person hasn't categorically said they think that. My often overly-logical brain might be imposing logic where it doesn't exist, though.

Comment: If someone says to me "What you said just now is sexist", and I say "I'm sorry if (or that) you think that", I am pointedly _not_ saying "I'm sorry for saying something sexist".

Comment: @MichaelHarvey oh yes, I wasn't arguing with the non-apology part.

Comment: SamBC - "it's mostly used when a person hasn't categorically said they think that", to what, then, does 'that' refer to?

Comment: I thought I was referring to the words in the original - I should have said *so* rather than *that*.

Comment: I should think that the OP should be advised about the difference between a genuine apology or acknowledgement, and a false apology that merely defies the critic, if for no other reason than that they can then deploy whichever they want. I know that really that would belong to Interpersonal Skills Stack Exchange.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey Added a note to that effect.

Comment: Perhaps the *if* is a hint that the criticism is insincere, and/or an invitation to correct your thinking.

Comment: @AntonSherwood aye, that makes sense.